# Copy N/A to another column and convert other rows to numeric in R

Tags: r, regex, text

I have a data frame with one row of string as follows:

```
     colA
1    Apples
2    Bats
3    Cats
4    N/A
5    Dogs and Pigs
6    N/A
```

I would like to copy each of the "N/A" items to the same row in a new column as NA, colB. I would like every other row that is not NA to be a numeric 0 or 1.

I have tried the following code plus a lot of other things:

```
df$colB = regmatches(df$colA, gregexpr("N/A", df$colA, perl=TRUE))
```

Thanks.

Comment: (1) You can't mix variable types in a vector. If colB contains "N/A" as strings, then the other values (0 or 1) will also be strings. (2) It's not clear what's meant by "numeric 0 or 1". What determines whether it's 0 or 1? Or did you mean all 0, or all 1? (3) The code in comment by d.b does not give the desired result.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that I want NA and 0's or NA and 1. I did not mean to mix variable types when asking the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want NA for "N/A" and 0 for everything else, you can use `ifelse`:

```
df$colB <- ifelse(df$colA == "N/A", NA, 0)
```

Comment: This works beautifully. I was getting very close to just looping through all the rows, but this works so much faster. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. Just remember that `ifelse` "returns a value with the same shape as test." In this case we compare a vector (column) and return a vector, so it works, but this aspect can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

How about `match()`, and a little trickery.

```
df$colB <- NA ^ match(df$colA, "N/A", 0L)
```

which gives

> ```
>            colA colB
> 1        Apples    1
> 2          Bats    1
> 3          Cats    1
> 4           N/A   NA
> 5 Dogs and Pigs    1
> 6           N/A   NA
> ```

Original data:

```
df <- structure(list(colA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Apples", 
"Bats", "Cats", "Dogs and Pigs", "N/A"), class = "factor")), .Names = "colA", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I like this solutions too. Thanks!